# sqlite3 database help in improving performance and design

Tags: select, sqlite, indexing, sql-like

I have a sqlite3 database with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dict] (
  [Entry] [CHAR(209)], 
  [Definition] [CHAR(924975)]);

CREATE INDEX [i_dict_entry] ON [dict] ([Entry]);
```

it's a kind of dictionary with 260000 records and nearly 1GB of size; I have created an index for the `Entry` column to improve performance;

a sample of a row's entry column is like this:

```
|love|lovingly|loves|loved|loving|
```

All the words which are separated with `|` are referring to the same definition;(I put all of them in one string, separated with `|` to prevent duplication of data in `Definition` column)

and this is the command that I use to retrieve the results:

```
SELECT * FROM dict WHERE Entry like '%|loves|%'
```

execution time: ~1.7s

if I use `=` operator instead of `LIKE` operator,  the execution is nearly instantaneous;

```
SELECT * FROM dict WHERE Entry='|love|lovingly|loves|loved|loving|'
```

but this way I can't search for words like: love,loves...(separately I mean)

My questions:

Although I have created an index for the `Entry` column, is indexing really effective while we are using `LIKE` operator with `%` in it?

what about the idea that I create different rows for each part of composite `Entry` columns(one for love another for loves...then all will have the same definition) and then use `=` operator? if yes; is there anyway of referencing of data? I mean rather than repeating the same `Definition` for each entry, create one and all others point to it; is it possible?

thanks in advance for any tip and suggestion;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every entry should have a separate row in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE Definitions (
    DefinitionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Definition TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE Entries (
    EntryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    DefinitionID INTEGER REFERENCES Definitions(DefinitionID),
    Entry TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX i_entry ON Entries(Entry);
```

You can then query the definition by joiing the two tables:

```
SELECT Definition
FROM Entries
JOIN Definitions USING (DefinitionID)
WHERE Entry = 'loves'
```

---

Also see [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: impressive! after coding for migration to new schema, here is the execution time for the query: 0.00099999999997635s